# Windows 8 apparently removes content-encoding header from compressed HTTP responses

Tags: http, windows-8, http-headers, http-compression

I'm not completely sure whether this belongs on SO, but I don't know where else to ask.

While I was checking the loading speed of a web app of mine I noticed that apparently no HTTP response (no matter what type - html, css, js) is gzip/deflate compressed. That is, no response header like "Content-Encoding: gzip" is present in any request and the browser reports that the resource is not compressed.

- tested and confirmed in multiple browsers (IE10, FF 17, Chrome 23, Opera 12.10, Safari 5.x)
- tested and confirmed on two machines running Windows 8 Pro
- double checked with Fiddler - the response is not compressed and does not contain a content-encoding header
- this doesn't only happen for my web apps, *no* other web site  I tested appears to send compressed responses (according to the browser)
- on Windows 7 the responses arrive compressed and with all headers
- HTTPS responses *are* compressed

Here's an example of the response headers (note the lack of the content-encoding header):
[image: response headers on client machine]

I also checked the server side. The server is running Windows Server 2008 R2/IIS 7.5. I used Failed Request Tracing to find out what the server is sending. The resource appears to be compressed:

[image: server side compression]

Also, the server seems to send the proper headers:

[image: compression headers]

My conclusion: it must be Windows 8 who is intervening here. Apparently it modifies HTTP responses. I suppose that Windows 8 is receiving the compressed response, decompresses it, removes the content-encoding header and passes the modified response further down the pipeline.

Now my questions:

- Can anybody confirm that Windows 8 modifies HTTP responses and that it works the way I described?
- Is there a way to monitor or even disable this behavior?

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Regards,
Andre

---

Update:
I used Wireshark to see what arrives at the client. As I expected the resources are compressed and the content-encoding header is still present. The image below shows the wireshark protocol and in the bottom right the response as received by Chrome.

[image: wireshark]

This confirms my assumption that Windows 8 is intervening.

Comment: Have you checked at the network level on the client with Wireshark? Maybe it's your ISP.

Comment: Do you have a proxy server or fancy router on your network? It may decompress the data to inspect it, and send the decompressed response to you.

Comment: I did the test with Windows 8 and Windows 7 machines on exactly the same network, ie. the same internet provider and the same network infrastructure. I'll try to dig into the network traffic with wireshark and see what I can find.

Comment: I updated my question with the Wireshark protocol: the response arrives compressed and with the content-encoding header but still appears as non-compressed in the browser. I'm really curious what Windows is doing here.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It turned out that the culprit was my antivirus software, Avast, more specifically the integrated real-time network-shield. Turning it off causes responses to appear compressed in the browsers again.

What remains interesting is that Avast was running on the Windows 7 machines as well, even though on those machines responses where compressed where applicable during my tests.

Comment: I have the same problem. But the browser still doesn't appear compressed after I turn off my antivirus software

Comment: Same exact thing is happening to me as well, and I'd suspect Microsoft's Windows Defender or one of Microsofts highly suspect "security updates" **long** before I'd suspect my AV software.  And yes, I disabled the AV and the problem still exists.